# drag drop doesn't work for dynamically inserted element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `div` which is a list of sections that are draggable.

I then have a drag and drop script which looks like this:

```js
const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task');

tasks.forEach(task => {

  task.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart, false);
  task.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
  task.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave, false);
  task.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
  task.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop, false);
  task.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd, false);

});



function dragStart(e) {
  //do something
};

function dragEnter(e) {
  //do something
}

function dragLeave(e) {
  //do somehting
}

function dragOver(e) {

  //do something
}

function dragDrop(e) {
  //do something 
}

function dragEnd(e) {

  //do something
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <section id="1" class="task" draggable="true">
    <p> Something here </p>
  </section>

  <section id="2" class="task" draggable="true">
    <p> Something here </p>
  </section>

  ...

</div>
```

Everything works perfectly (every section can be drag & drop).

Yet if instead of having a static HTML I do: `document.getElementById('list').insertHTML(//my draggable sections)` then my js script doesn't seems to work anymore. I can't drag & drop my sections.

I don't understand why, it seems like inserting the sections dynamically change something but I don't understand what... Is there a way to fix this problem ?

Comment: can you show the code you are using to add the element dynamically so we can help debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by `element.insertHTML()` do you `element.insertAdjacentHTML()`?
Anyways, I would guess that there's an issue with code execution order, it's probably running

```
const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
```

before you change html inside `.list` element. This means that `const tasks` ends up being empty array(it's actually empty NodeList but doesn't metter here)

Also if you don't have any specific reason to use `insertAdjacentHTML`, I would recomend you to use `appendChild` instead.

**UPD**

Also, every time you add new items to your list you would have to add eventListeners to each node you added.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry, I am actually using innerHTML, but it seems like even if I compute tasks after it still doesn't work and I don't get why ?

Comment: maybe innerHTML delete events idk

Comment: @Question1010 If you don't have any basic human error or misuse there, `innerHTML` only changes the value and doesn't render the nodes(elements into DOM). This would be a more advanced topic, if you wan't to learn more lookup 'js event loop' on google.
But as I said in initial answer, it's better to use `appendChild()` if you wan't to add event listeners to the nodes.
Another tip would be to `console.log(tasks)` before you adding event listeners, so you know if there are any nodes `.task` in your DOM at the moment of adding event listeners.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, that's very interesting ! I am going to lookup for js event loop :)